# Нужен ли какой-то знак препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Такое предложение: "Как-то в супермаркете провели опрос: по какому принципу люди выбирают товар (в данном случае моющие средства)". Так вот, меня интересует, нужен ли какой-то знак препинания после "в данном случае"?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Или ничего(в данном случае это моющие средства) , или тире(в данном случае выбирают моющие средства).